# Fonts from custom math command does not get resized in subscripts and superscripts

Tags: macros, fontsize, subscripts, superscripts

I have a particular type of symbol in my document that I want to typeset in a different font. Hence, I defined a macro `\tn` to make this shorter. After several attempts, I ended up with the definition showed in the MWE, which is fine in most cases. But when I use `\tn` in subscripts or superscripts, the symbols are not re-sized properly, and the equations look inconsistent.

I need to change the definition of `\tn` so the symbols are consistent in size when used in subscripts and/or superscripts.

Thanks,

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\ensuremath\mbox{\boldmath$\mathsf{#1}$}}
\begin{document}
Good sizes \[h=\tn{A}+\tn{B}^2 + \hat{\tn{C}}\]

But the sizes are bad when superscripts or subscripts are involved
\[k=\underbrace{\hat{\tn{C}}}_{\hat{\tn{C}}}+\overbrace{\mathbf{u}}^{\mathbf{u}}+\tn{D}^{\tn{D}}
+\mathbf{v}^{\mathbf{v}}\]

Look how size of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is smaller in the superscripts, but $\tn{C}$ and $\tn{D}$ are the same. Even worse, the hat accent over $\hat{\tn{C}}$ is resized in the subscript, so it's not consistent
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\mbox`. Instead, load the `amsmath` package and use the `\text` command.

Comment: @Mico Dude, I love you, in a platonic way... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automatic sizing of material in subscript and superscript positions, don't use the basic `\mbox` command. (Here, "basic" means "defined in the LaTeX kernel.) Instead, be sure to load the `amsmath` package and use the `\text` command. The setup of the `\tn` macro should thus be as follows:

```
\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\text{\boldmath$\mathsf{#1}$}}
```

Because `\tn` only ever seems to get used inside math mode material, I would also dispense with the `\ensuremath` wrapper..

Comment: I wanted to add the ``\ensuremath`` to avoid putting the math specifier ``$ $`` inside the macro, but I guess I got it backwards. It was giving errors, and at the end, I left both in the definition. Thanks for the extra tip

Comment: @phollox - Indeed, oth `\mbox` and `\text` treat their arguments as text-mode material. Any math material in their arguments must therefore be encased in `$` symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `bm` can be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Good sizes (and $\mathsf{A}$ for comparison)
\[
h=\tn{A}+\tn{B}^2 + \hat{\tn{C}}
\]

But the sizes are bad when superscripts or subscripts are involved
\[k=\underbrace{\hat{\tn{C}}}_{\hat{\tn{C}}}+\overbrace{\mathbf{u}}^{\mathbf{u}}+\tn{D}^{\tn{D}}
+\mathbf{v}^{\mathbf{v}}\]

Look how size of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is smaller in the superscripts, but $\tn{C}$ and
$\tn{D}$ are the same. Even worse, the hat accent over $\hat{\tn{C}}$ is resized in the subscript, so
it's not consistent

\end{document}
```

[image]

An even cleaner solution, if you aren't short of math groups:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\mathsfbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

Good sizes (and $\mathsf{A}$ for comparison)
\[
h=\tn{A}+\tn{B}^2 + \hat{\tn{C}}
\]

But the sizes are bad when superscripts or subscripts are involved
\[k=\underbrace{\hat{\tn{C}}}_{\hat{\tn{C}}}+\overbrace{\mathbf{u}}^{\mathbf{u}}+\tn{D}^{\tn{D}}
+\mathbf{v}^{\mathbf{v}}\]

Look how size of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is smaller in the superscripts, but $\tn{C}$ and
$\tn{D}$ are the same. Even worse, the hat accent over $\hat{\tn{C}}$ is resized in the subscript, so
it's not consistent

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Neat. The command ``\DeclareMathAlphabet`` creates a math font type called in this case ``\mathsfbf``. I'll have to check the help to see what the other commands do. I might use this. I have several custom math groups, including one for bold greek letters that also uses ``\mbox`` and that would present the same problem as the original ``\tn``. I'll try to use this to define an alternative ``\mathbf`` that supports greek letters. Something like ``\mathrmbf`` maybe? In my current configuration, ``\mathbf{u}`` produces bold text but ``\mathbf{\phi}`` produces regular text. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. ``\mathrmbf{\phi}`` produces regular text. Probably a work for ``bm``. Thanks again for the alternative!

Comment: @phollox I've never said that you can apply `\mathrmbf` to something other than a letter; it's the same for `\mathbf{\phi}`, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. It was just me random testing things.